# On Popup data fetch is seen twice through ajax : php mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am struggling from past 2 hours .

Tried :

```
location.reload();
reset form
```

many features but after i close my popup and when reopen or open some another id ..my previous id data is still seen there and its continuous for all id.

**style :**

```
#overlay {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #000;
filter:alpha(opacity=70);
-moz-opacity:0.7;
-khtml-opacity: 0.7;
opacity: 0.7;
z-index: 100;
display: none;
}
.content a{
text-decoration: none;
}
.popup{
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
display: none;
position: fixed; 
z-index: 101;
}
.content{
min-width: 800px;
width: 900px;
min-height: 150px;
margin: 0px auto;
background: #f3f3f3;
position: relative;
z-index: 103;
padding: 10px;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #000;
}
.content p{
clear: both;
color: #555555;
text-align: justify;
}
.content p a{
color: #d91900;
font-weight: bold;
}
.content .x{
float: right;
height: 35px;
left: 22px;
position: relative;
top: -25px;
width: 34px;
}
.content .x:hover{
cursor: pointer;
}
```

**Jquery / ajax :**

Below is my popup box + ajax to fetch and show record under Input field

```
 $('#class').on('click delegate mouseenter', 'a', function (e) {

            var data = dt.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
            var valuea = data[1];


             $(function(){
                e.preventDefault();   
                var table = $('#class').DataTable();
                var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
                    $('.close').click(function(){
                    $('.popup').hide();
                    overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
                    location.reload();
                    resetForms();
                    $("span.ajax_loader").hide(); // success
                    var pathlaser = "server_processing_laser.php";
                    tablel.clear();
                    tablel.draw();
                    tablel.ajax.url(pathlaser).load();
                    return false;
                });

                $('.xclose').click(function(){
                    $('.popup').hide();
                    overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
                    location.reload();
                    resetForms();
                    $("span.ajax_loader").hide(); // success
                    var pathlaser = "server_processing_laser.php";
                    tablel.clear();
                    tablel.draw();
                    tablel.ajax.url(pathlaser).load();
                    return false;
                });

             // POPUP BOX

                $('.click_'+data[0]+'').click(function(e){e.preventDefault();       
                    overlay.show();
                    overlay.appendTo(document.body);
                    $('.popup').show();
                $("div.note_msg").hide();
                    $('.popup .id').val(valuea); 

               // FETCHING DATA TO SHOW

                    $.ajax({
                       type:"GET",
                       url:"fetchrecord.php",
                       data:{
                           valuea:valuea,

                        },
                         async: false,
                       success:function(html){ 
                         $("#display").after(html);
                         }     
                    });

                    return false;
                });

            });
    }); 

});
```

**below is popup code :**

```
<div class='popup'>
<div class='content'>
<a href='' class="xclose"><img src='../datatables/media/images/close.png' alt='quit' class='x' id='x' /> </a>
<p> 
         <form method="post" action="" id="feedback_form">

        <div class="langtrx_fr" align="center">
                <table align="center"> 
                 <div id="display"></div>

               </table>

        </div> 
    </form>


<span class="ajax_loader"></span>

<table align="center"><tr><td> <a href='' class='close'><strong>Close</strong></a> </td></tr> </table>

</p>
</div>
</div>
```

**fetchrecord.php**

```
$valuepktid = $_REQUEST['valuea'];

$sql = "SELECT stoneone,stonetwo,stone3,loss FROM stone
      WHERE pid = ".db_escape($valuepktid)." 
      GROUP BY id";
$resultpkt = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$abpkt = mysqli_fetch_array($resultpkt); 

?>

<?php


?>


<tr> 
<td class="label">Stone 1 :</td>
<td  class="form">
<input name="stoneone" id="stoneone" readonly value="<?php echo $abpkt['stoneone'];?>" class="stoneone" autocomplete="off"  type="number"/>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="label">Stone 2 :</td>
<td class="form"><input name="stonetwo" readonly value="<?php echo $abpkt['stonetwo'];?>" class="stonetwo" autocomplete="off"  type="number" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="label">Loss :</td>
<td class="form"><input name="loss" readonly  value="<?php echo $abpkt['loss'];?>" class="loss" value="" autocomplete="off"  type="number" /></td>
</tr>
```

All is working fine.. i mean i am getting data

but when i close and open any other ID , then popup show me above tr/td data twice.
means the latest data and the old one which i closed.
i tried reload of page so that i get fresh data, but some time its showing me proper data and some time multiple with old one.

I think its something related to cache of DIV. which remain as its after close of popup.

**popup link :** [Jquery Datatables : Jquery Popup Box not working under function - php mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24902935/jquery-datatables-jquery-popup-box-not-working-under-function-php-mysql)

any idea please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my the answer :

**Changed below :**

```
success:function(html) { 

$("#display").after(html);

}
```

**TO :**

```
success:function(data) { 

$("#display").html(data);

}
```

Its working now, no repeat is happening now.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
header('Pragma: no-cache', true);
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate", true);
```

in fetchrecord.php

Comment: hey as suggested i tried to put above in fetchrecord.php  before tr under <?php header('Pragma: no-cache', true);
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate", true); ?>  but after close and open again popup so old + new  data under  #display

Answer (score 0):

I admit, I didn't give this a proper read, but try $('feedback_form').trigger("reset"); after you're done with the form.

Comment: hey thanks for response, i had tried that already but result was same :(

Comment: How about setting the div contents to '' in the close trigger?

Comment: sorry i dint get you .. can you please tell me in detail

Comment: try $('.popup .id').val('')